# Why dollar sign is used to detect jQuery version?

Tags: jquery

I often see in many jQuery plugins like below:

```
var version= $ && $().jquery.split(/\./);
```

I can understand `$().jquery` as it produces the version of jQuery but before this why just `$` sign is used which produces `function(a,b)` if I use `console.log($);`

So, why `$` is used here?

Comment: because `$()` will throw a syntax error if `$` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript operators also return the evaluated statement.

So because the statement is `true`, the `&&` operator also returns the righthand statement `$().jquery.split(/\./);`.

A more common example would be this: `debug && console.log(msg)`, meaning when `debug` is true, return `console.log(msg)`

The `||` would return the first statement that evaluates to `true`: `"hello" || false; // "hello"`

Comment: It means last true condition will be placed. Thanks... I was thinking a wrong... that if first condition is right then it would take place...

Comment: For the `&&` operator, al foregoing conditions must evaluate to true as well!

Answer (score 0):

`$ && $()` If the left hand side of that statement is false, the right hand side will not be executed. This ensures that `$` is truthy before attempting to execute it as a function. It isn't fool proof, because it will still throw a syntax error if `$` is equal to something other than a function that is also truthy, such as the string `"foobar"`.

Basically, it just ensures that `$` exists before attempting to execute it as a function. If it doesn't exist, `version` will equal undefined or whatever was stored in `$`